# Resign or stay?, great opportunity vs tough situation

Tags: job-offer

I'll give you some background on my question so you can understand why is this a little difficult for me.

I'm a programmer, I work at a Venezuelan startup, i'm currently the lead developer and I cherry-picked all my team within the best students I knew when I was teacher's assistant at the university, so, I really like the project and the team is great, we work really good together.

On the other hand, the startup is based on Caracas, the 2nd or 3rd most dangerous city in the world, I'm used to this, I know how to take care of myself, but also, (I don't know is everybody reads the news or if we appear at all...) the current political situation in Venezuela is very delicate, the inflation eats almost all my salary (I had to return to my parent's place because I couldn't afford to rent, buy food and pay for my medical insurance at the same time and our relation isn't the best at all). My salary used to be something like $1200/month and now, after the latest devaluation, is about $124/month. To make my point, our highest amount bill (VEF 100), is not enough to buy one canned tuna, which currently costs VEF 145. And, to make things a little more delicate, i'm about to get married... so... yes...

Recently, I received an offer which includes paid relocation a great salary, medical insurance and it means a way out of the current tough country situation for me and my fiance.

So, the thing is, I once had a similar opportunity and, when I resigned, they made a counteroffer and made me partner, so, now i'm a partner (in theory), but my personal situation has radically changed from then to now, even if I still love my job, my personal situation is really tough and there is no possibility of a pay rise or something like that (already discussed that), the other partner's situation is really nice, or at least it seems to be, his parents own a construction company and has several contracts with the government...

So, the thing is, what would you do?, how should I resign if i know I have to... but i don't want to :S. Difficult decision

Comment: "I need advice on...", "What should I do?", or "Which job should I take?" questions are off topic on The Workplace I'm afraid - help topic is here: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Run like hell. That's what I'd do.

Comment: @CodingKiwi i'm sorry, I should read that. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexM. Hey dude!

Comment: @Almo hiya man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd leave an never look back.  That said, I don't live anywhere near there so this is a complete outsiders point of view.

First off, I wouldn't want to raise a family in an area that is not only dangerous but also one in which I couldn't support them.  I'm not sure about you, but that would be demoralizing to me.  Even being a "partner" or having recently received a raise is meaningless if you can't afford to pay your own way.  I wouldn't call that a great opportunity.

Next, economies with super high inflation tend to get a LOT worse before they get better.  There is a lot of pain that the Venezuelan government needs to go through in order to get the economy back in order.  From what I've seen news wise, and with a bit of history as a guide, I just don't feel like this is going to be solved any time soon.

Also, I wouldn't feel bad about being the reason several people joined that company.  Everyone is responsible for their own decisions and you likely presented things truthfully at the time you brought them in.  Presumably they live and work in the same area you do so they should have the same information from which to make their own decisions.  The world has now changed for you and it's perfectly normal and acceptable to reevaluate your personal goals.  If you decide to leave they will make up their own minds about what to do.